# SRIOV + ubuntu bonding in KVM

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, network-bonding

I have a KVM with Intel SRIOV card.

```
5: enp4s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:bd:05:d9:82 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    vf 0 MAC 00:0c:bd:05:d9:11, spoof checking off, link-state auto
    vf 1 MAC 00:0c:bd:05:d9:ab, spoof checking off, link-state auto
    vf 2 MAC 00:0c:bd:05:d9:a2, spoof checking off, link-state auto
    vf 3 MAC 00:0c:bd:05:d9:ac, spoof checking off, link-state auto
    vf 4 MAC 00:0c:bd:05:d9:ad, spoof checking off, link-state auto
    vf 5 MAC 00:0c:bd:05:d9:ae, spoof checking off, link-state auto
    vf 6 MAC 00:0c:bd:05:d9:af, spoof checking off, link-state auto
    vf 7 MAC 00:0c:bd:05:d9:a1, spoof checking off, link-state auto
8: enp4s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:bd:05:d9:83 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    vf 0 MAC 00:0c:bd:05:d9:12, spoof checking off, link-state auto
    vf 1 MAC 00:0c:bd:05:d9:bb, spoof checking off, link-state auto
    vf 2 MAC 00:0c:bd:05:d9:bc, spoof checking off, link-state auto
    vf 3 MAC 00:0c:bd:05:d9:bd, spoof checking off, link-state auto
    vf 4 MAC 00:0c:bd:05:d9:be, spoof checking off, link-state auto
    vf 5 MAC 00:0c:bd:05:d9:bf, spoof checking off, link-state auto
    vf 6 MAC 00:0c:bd:05:d9:b1, spoof checking off, link-state auto
    vf 7 MAC 00:0c:bd:05:d9:b2, spoof checking off, link-state auto
```

I have used vf0 from each card in a GUEST Ubuntu machine

Physical Function enp4s0f0 has the following virtual functions:

```
PCI BDF         Interface
=======         =========
0000:04:10.0
0000:04:10.2
0000:04:10.4
0000:04:10.6
0000:04:11.0
0000:04:11.2
0000:04:11.4
0000:04:11.6
```

Physical Function enp4s0f1 has the following virtual functions:

```
PCI BDF         Interface
=======         =========
0000:04:10.1
0000:04:10.3
0000:04:10.5
0000:04:10.7
0000:04:11.1
0000:04:11.3
0000:04:11.5
```

Snippet of dumpxml

```
<interface type='hostdev'>
  <mac address='00:0c:bd:05:d9:11'/>
  <driver name='vfio'/>
  <source>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x10' function='0x0'/>
  </source>
  <alias name='hostdev0'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
<interface type='hostdev'>
  <mac address='00:0c:bd:05:d9:12'/>
  <driver name='vfio'/>
  <source>
    <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x10' function='0x1'/>
  </source>
  <alias name='hostdev1'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

## My bonding configuration:

```
uto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet manual
bond-master bond0



auto bond0
iface bond0 inet static
address 192.168.23.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
bond-slaves none
bond-mode 2
bond-miimon 100
bond-downdelay 0
bond-updelay 0

cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: load balancing (xor)
Transmit Hash Policy: layer2 (0)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: eth1
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:0c:bd:05:d9:11
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eth2
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:0c:bd:05:d9:12
Slave queue ID: 0


bond0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:bd:05:d9:11
          inet addr:192.168.23.101  Bcast:192.168.23.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:bdff:fe05:d911/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:122 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:295 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:33881 (33.8 KB)  TX bytes:34294 (34.2 KB)


eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:bd:05:d9:11
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:122 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:183 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:33881 (33.8 KB)  TX bytes:28212 (28.2 KB)

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:bd:05:d9:11
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          **RX packets:0** errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:112 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:6082 (6.0 KB)
```

Here bond0 MAC is same as eth1 MAC as eth1 came up first. Issues is when I receive packets in PF corresponding to eth2, packets are recieved in GUEST(eth2), eth2 RX is 0 ...

What could be the issue? Sometimes eth2 comes up first after reboot and bond0 has eth2 MAC and at that point eth1 RX is zero.